# How does CoffeeScript decide function parameter priorities?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Suppose we have 3 functions: times, plus and minus. They do what their name suggest. We then create the following line in JavaScript:

```
times(plus(1,2) ,minus(5,2));
```

When written in CoffeeScript, it's:

```
times plus 1,2 , minus 5,2
```

And after compiled to JavaScript, it becomes:

```
(function() {
  times(plus(1, 2, minus(5, 2)));
}).call(this);
```

Which is not what we want. Is there a CoffeeScript way to solve this or we have to use brackets? Thanks,

Comment: Speaking as a mathematician, this is exactly why parentheses were invented in the first place.

Comment: Do not nest bracketless function calls, ever, in Ruby, or CoffeeScript, or any other language that allows them. The fact those even allow omitting the brackets anywhere except in the outermost of nested function calls instead of bailing with a syntax error is a horrible misfeature.

Comment: @Xi you **can** use parenthesis. Please, please, please, do it. It is not because you are using CoffeeScript that you have to avoid parenthesis at all costs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I explain in [my book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript), there's no way for the compiler to know what rule you want to use for implicit parentheses. Sure, in the case

```
times plus 1,2, minus 5,2
```

it's obvious to a human that you'd want it to mean

```
times(plus(1,2), minus(5,2))
```

But you might also write

```
times 5, plus 1, parseInt str, 10
```

and expect it to be understood (as it is) as

```
times(5, plus(1, parseInt(str, 10))
```

The rule for CoffeeScript's implicit parentheses is very simple: They go to the end of the expression. So, for instance, you can always stick `Math.floor` in front of a mathematical expression.

As a stylistic matter, I generally only omit parens for the first function call on a line, thus avoiding any potential confusion. That means I'd write your example as

```
times plus(1,2), minus(5,2)
```

Not bad, right?

Comment: +1 for "I generally only omit parens for the first function call on a line, thus avoiding any potential confusion."

Comment: I hope that CoffeeLint could warn when the argument interpretation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the "regular" function-call parens, you can use the paren-less style for the function *call* and parens only for *precedence*, such as:

```
times (plus 1, 2), (minus 5, 2)
```

Of course, it's only a matter of taste; the `times plus(1, 2), minus(5, 2)` version works just as well.